# How to update column of a table after group by with condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new user of `SQL` with `C#`. I'm faced a problem, I have SQL table where some `column` these are:

```
id, receiptNo, modelName, size, quantity, pricePerUnit, totalPrice.
```

After `group by size` column I want to `update` '`quantity`' column with condition.

Condition is, I want to decrease/minus/less/update '`quantity`' row after row. When 'quantity' is '0' then its jump to the next row & find the quantity & decrease this.

Here is data:

```
|id | |receiptNo| |modelName| |size| |quantity| |pricePerUnit| |totalPrice|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1|   |001|       |ABCD|      |XXL|  |0|        |120|          |0| 

|2|   |002|       |ABCD|      |XXL|  |6|        |120|          |720|

|3|   |003|       |ABCD|      |XXL|  |7|        |120|          |840|

|4|   |004|       |APPP|      |XL |  |2|        |60 |          |120|
```

I want to decrease from first 3 rows '`8`' quantities using group by size column. how could I do that?

Comment: didn't understand you well, explain more, or provide the desired result

Comment: I am adding Desired results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like that :

```
UPDATE Your_Table SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 
WHERE Quantity <>0 AND Size = 'XXL' 
AND Id  = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Your_Table WHERE Quantity = 
    (SELECT MIN(Quantity) FROM Your_Table WHERE Size='XXL')
)
```

It will decrease the quantity for the first line of the size 'XXL' where the quantity is the minimum.

this is to decrease by one. You might be able to call it 8 time then :)

I haven't test the request. It may need some adjustment.